# AWS Kendra sdk call will not return results

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kendra

I have been following the AWS-Kendra react-search app example you can find here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/deploying.html

After importing the Kendra client with:

```
const kendra = require('aws-sdk/clients/kendra');
const kendraClient = new kendra({apiVersion: '2019-02-03', region: 'us-east-1'});
```

Any call on kendraClient to any of the kendra services returns null. I have been executing queries with:

```
const results = kendraClient.query({ IndexId: INDEX_ID, QueryText: queryText});
```

Which returns a request object with null data and error fields.

I have calls to S3 which execute correctly in the same file so I do not believe it to be an authentication problem. If I had to guess it's some issue with how I created the kendra object and client, the usual

```
kendra = new AWS.Kendra();
```

doesn't work because Kendra is not part of the browser version of the SDK.

Comment: It looks like you might not be getting any matching documents for the given query. Could you please confirm if you are getting any results in AWS Kendra console for the given query text for your Kendra index?

Comment: @rotenstein It's has been a while. "doesn't work because Kendra is not part of the browser version of the SDK." Do you have any plan to add this in the browser version of SDK?

Comment: Please refer to Kendra.ts in sample web application we distribute here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/deploying.html for JS code reference on initializing Kendra client

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to run js from browser directly? Here is a sample nodejs code

```
var kendra = require("aws-sdk/clients/kendra");
var kendraClient = new kendra({apiVersion: "2019-02-03", region: "us-west-2"});
exports.handler = function (event)  {
    try{
        console.log("Starting....");
        var params = {
            IndexId: "<<Enter your indexId here>>",
            QueryText: "<<Enter your queryText here>>",
            QueryResultTypeFilter: "DOCUMENT",
            PageNumber: 1
        };
        
        var kendraResponse = kendraClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
                      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                      else     console.log("Kendra result is", data);           // successful response
                    });
                    
    const response = {
                "dialogAction":
                    {
                     "fulfillmentState":"Fulfilled",
                     "type":"Close","message":
                        {
                          "contentType":"PlainText"
                        }
                    }
                }

    return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
};
```